# how to solve tesseract error in windows server 2012 environment

Tags: java, visual-c++, dll, tesseract

I've been unable to find any solution of my issue which i got while running "doOCR" method: **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError : The specified module could not be found**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llFHh.jpg)

And it's running on Windows Server 2012 64 bit.

What I'd done for this are below:

- read some similar cases with mine but still didn't figure it out.
- read tutorial of Tess4j
- installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable x64
- checked required .jar files which were downloaded from "https://github.com/tesseract-ocr": tess4j, jan-4.1.0, ghost4j , etcs..

And I doubt the system temp folder according to what Quan Nguyen suggested at: "https://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/6e800065/"
but I couldn't find it.

What is clear is that there is no temp folder of tess4j about "gsdll64.dll, liblept171.dll, libtesseract304.dll".

Comment: have you solved this issue? I have the same problem only in Win Server 2012.